# Cloning DIVs and setting parameters around children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a function that duplicates a text input field and it's containing div when the return key is hit. The div clones correctly with the input element, but does anyone have suggestions on how to clear the contents of that input element and focus on it?

JavaScript:

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var currentInput = $(this).parent("div");
        currentInput.clone().val('').insertAfter(currentInput).focus();
        return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="item_container">   
        <input type="text" class="data-entry">
    </div>
```

Comment: hi friend, a major problem here is that when you clone your `div` then you have multiple divs with same `id`s in your DOM, which is prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var currentInput = $(this).parent("div");
    currentInput.clone().insertAfter(currentInput).find('.data-entry').val('').focus();
    return false;
}
```